# How to calculate the minimum distance from the edge of any two circle SVGs

Tags: javascript, svg, ecmascript-6

I know you would typically use the pythagoras theorem to get the distance between points, but a circle doesn't have a x1 and x2. Here's an example. Without these values how can I calculate the distances?

```css
circle {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<svg transform="translate(0, 22)">
  <circle class="point" cx="121.78235294117647" cy="13.200000000000001" r="3.1058823529411765" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" data-values="[0.047]"></circle>
  <circle class="point" cx="125.2764705882353" cy="30.28235294117647" r="3.1058823529411765" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" data-values="[0.042]"></circle>
  <circle class="point" cx="112.8529411764706" cy="30.67058823529412" r="3.1058823529411765" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" data-values="[0.037]"></circle>
  <circle class="point" cx="103.53529411764706" cy="32.22352941176471" r="3.1058823529411765" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" data-values="[0.047]">
</svg>
```

Comment: Please specify what "distance" you mean - the minimum distance between any two points of any two circles, or the distance between two circle centers, or ...?

Comment: I would like to know the minimum distance between any two circles

Comment: From the center of the circle or the edge of the circle?

Comment: I would like to know it from the edge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distance between two circles is equal to the distance of their centers minus the sum of their radii.

```js
function distanceOfPoints(p0, p1) {
    let dx = p0.x - p1.x;
    let dy = p0.y - p1.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

function distanceOfCircles(cen0, rad0, cen1, rad1) {
    // if the circles intersect, our distance might be negative
    return Math.max(0, distanceOfPoints(cen0, cen1) - rad0 - rad1);
}
```

In the SVG, `cx` and `cy` are the centers of the circle (`cen0`, `cen1`) and `r` is their radius (`rad0`, `rad1`).

To obtain the minimum distance between ALL circles, you can loop through all pairs of circles and update your result-distance whenever you find a lower one.

Comment: ha you're right squaring negatives do end up absolute. that is cool

Comment: This all makes sense except the distanceOfPoints function.  If you pass in cen0 and cen1 they don't have an x property. CX is equal to an integer.

Comment: @Rafael I omitted the fact that you have to put `cx` and `cy` into a vector like `{x: cx, y:cy}`. You can also write the functions so that they take `cxN, cyN` instead of `cenN`, but then you would have a function that takes 6 parameters and it's not as elegant.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the minimum distance between two circles, you first take a vector that connects the two circle centers and calculate its length. Afterwards, you subtract the radii of both circles because the closest points of both circles must be away from the circle center exactly in the distance of each radius.

**Edit:** The horizontal and vertical distance values do not have to be positive because they will be squared in the next step anyhow (thanks to @Jan Schultke for the advice).

```js
const circle1 = {
  x: 13,      // horizontal center coordinate
  y: 4,       // vertical center coordinate
  radius: 5
};

const circle2 = {
  x: 9,      // horizontal center coordinate
  y: 24,       // vertical center coordinate
  radius: 3
};

function minimumDistance(circle1, circle2) {
  const horizontalDistance = circle1.x - circle2.x;
  const verticalDistance = circle1.y - circle2.y;

  const distanceBetweenCenter = Math.sqrt(horizontalDistance**2 + verticalDistance**2);  // pythagoras

  return distanceBetweenCenter - circle1.radius - circle2.radius;
}

console.log(minimumDistance(circle1, circle2));
```

Comment: You don't need to use `Math.abs` for the distances because they get squared in the next step. The result of squaring is always positive.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question interesting yesterday.

My answer is more literal to the question based on both [@Spark Fountain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2764486/spark-fountain) and [@Jan Schultke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5740428/jan-schultke) great answers. The concepts are theirs.

The javascript below is based on each `svg` circle having its own unique ID.

```js
// find our distance between two svg circles by id
function distance(circle1,circle2) {

    // get our specified circles by id
    let c1 = document.getElementById(circle1);
    let c2 = document.getElementById(circle2);
    
    // circle one attributes
    c1 = {
      x: c1.getAttribute("cx"),
      y: c1.getAttribute("cy"),
      r: c1.getAttribute("r")
    };
  
    // circle two attributes
    c2 = {
      x: c2.getAttribute("cx"),   
      y: c2.getAttribute("cy"),
      r: c2.getAttribute("r")
    };
     
    // lets work out each x and y axis distance
    // not too worry about negative values
    let x = c1.x - c2.x;
    let y = c1.y - c2.y;
    
    // lets work out the hypotenuse between x and y using pythagoras
    // negative x or y values become absolute when squared
    let distance = Math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2);
    
    // now minus the radius of both circles from our distance
    // to equal the distance from the edge of the circles
    // math.max largest of zero or more incase circles overlap
    distance = Math.max(0, distance - c1.r - c2.r);
      
    console.log('distance between circle ' + circle1 + ' and ' + circle2 + ' is ' + distance);
    
    // return the distance
    return distance;
    
}

// check your console for distance
distance('4','3');
distance('1','2');
distance('3','1');
distance('2','3');
```

```html
<svg transform="translate(0, 22)">
  <circle id="1" class="point" cx="121.78235294117647" cy="13.200000000000001" r="3.1058823529411765" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" data-values="[0.047]"></circle>
  <circle id="2" class="point" cx="125.2764705882353" cy="30.28235294117647" r="3.1058823529411765" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" data-values="[0.042]"></circle>
  <circle id="3" class="point" cx="112.8529411764706" cy="30.67058823529412" r="3.1058823529411765" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" data-values="[0.037]"></circle>
  <circle id="4" class="point" cx="103.53529411764706" cy="32.22352941176471" r="3.1058823529411765" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1" data-values="[0.047]"></circle>
</svg>
```